# Toyota prado 2015 map disk error

Tags: toyota, diy, navigation, land-cruiser, prado

I see this in Toyota Prado Land Cruiser 2015[image]

Which in english it says: `Unable to load program please consult your dealer.`

How can I (preferably DIY) solve this?

Additional Photo incase you need more info about the system:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!